# C++ Binary Read Write Files

Tags: c++, file, binary

ok so im on the 2nd Semester on my unversity have done c and doing c++ now
doing the project in DevC.

Currently im making a program that will do the charging processes of a shop while having and editing the database.

Tried writing and reading a full struct but dosent work so i went down writing 2 int numbers and reading them but this also dosent work while getting random number when reading even though if i write txt the numbers seem ok.

```
//write and read are different fucntion only 1 is called .
//file creation code
int AccountNumber=0;
ofstream FileCreator("Database.dat",ios::binary);   
FileCreator<<AccountNumber;
AccountNumber=1;
FileCreator<<AccountNumber;
```

and

```
//reading code

int AccountNumber=0;
ifstream FileCreator("Database.dat",ios::binary);
FileCreator.seekg(0,ios::beg);

FileCreator.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&AccountNumber), sizeof(AccountNumber));
cout<<AccountNumber<<endl;
FileCreator.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&AccountNumber), sizeof(AccountNumber));
cout<<AccountNumber<<endl;
```

I expect 0 and 1 at the output but get 12592 and 12592.

Comment: For binary writing, use `std::ostream::write`, not `operator<<`.  So, `FileCreator<<AccountNumber` should be replaced by `FileCreator.write((char *) &AccountNumber, sizeof(AccountNumber))`.

Comment: you mean you expect 0 and **1** (not 50)

Comment: Hello EJLH. Unrelated, but might be of interest to you: [mcve].

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ooof that fixed it  thank you  :D .but why does it matter ? does << write differently that .write in binary files ?

Comment: to open in binary is only useful under Windows to not have the \n transformed on the fly to \c\n

Comment: Using the `operator>>` converts the integer from internal format to human readable format.  Assuming ASCII and the integer 23654, the `operator<<` will write bytes: 0x32, 0x33, 0x36, 0x35, 0x34, which is 5 bytes.  When writing the internal format for 4-byte integers, the binary representation (Big Endian) would be: 0x00005c66.

Comment: @EmptyJustLikeHeaven you can mix write/read and <</>> , see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *writing* binary files, use `std::ostream::write()` method, not `operator<<`:

```
FileCreator.write((char *) &AccountNumber, sizeof(AccountNumber));
```

The cast is necessary because there is no overload for writing integers to the stream.

Remember, `read` and `write` are paired for binary I/O.

**Edit 1: Fixed length & variable length records**
Be aware that you need the *size* of the item when writing and reading.  This will work for fixed size/length data items and structures.  However, it does not work well with variable length data, such as text.

For variable length records, you may want to write the length first followed by the data:

```
static const char hello[] = "Hello";
static const unsigned int data_size(sizeof(hello) - 1);
FileCreator.write((char *) &data_size, sizeof(data_size));
FileCreator.write(&hello[0], data_size);
```

In the above example, the "- 1" is there so that the terminating NUL character is not written to the file.  You don't need this for binary files, but YMMV (I use the idiom when writing to console and other human readable streams).

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer of @Thomas Matthews

> but why does it matter ? does << write differently that .write in binary files ?

Out of windows you will not see a difference, under windows the \n are saved/read unchanged if the file open in binary mode, else a writting `\n` produces `\r\n` and reading `\c\n` returns `\n`. It like the difference between "r"/"rb" and "w"/"wb" for *fopen*.

You can mix the use of the operator `<</>>` and read/write in binary mode or not but you have to take care of the separators, for instance :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int AccountNumber = 123;

  {
    ofstream bin("bin",ios::binary);   

    bin << AccountNumber << '\n'; // a \n to finish the number allowing to read it later
    bin.write((char *) &AccountNumber, sizeof(AccountNumber));
  }
  {
    ofstream txt("txt");   

    txt << AccountNumber << '\n';
    txt.write((char *) &AccountNumber, sizeof(AccountNumber));
  }
  {
    ifstream bin("bin",ios::binary);

    AccountNumber = 0;
    bin >> AccountNumber;
    cout << AccountNumber << endl;

    // I have to read the \n with read() because >> bypass it.
    // Supposing I written '@' rather than '\n' `bin >> c;` can be used
    char c;

    bin.read(&c, 1);
    cout << (int) c << endl;

    AccountNumber = 0;
    bin.read((char *) &AccountNumber, sizeof(AccountNumber));
    cout << AccountNumber << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution (out of Windows) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall f.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
123
10
123
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cmp txt bin
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

I am not under Windows so to use the binary mode or not changes nothing, the two files are identical

Comment: I'm not sure but I suspect that `bin.read(&c, 1);` won't work well on Windows. `bin.ignore();` would probably be better.

Comment: Turns out, neither `bin.read(&c, 1);` nor `bin.ignore();` works in binary mode on windows. One has to manually read the 2 EOL chars. So mixing stream operators and `read`/`write` seems to be a little more complicated on Windows.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, the auto transformation between \n and \c\n is only active when using the operator <</>>, so a mix operator/function for \n is a problem under Windows